# Load and use sqlite file in google colab

Tags: sqlite, google-colaboratory

```
print ('Files in Drive:')

!ls drive/AI`
```

'database.sqlite' file is already present in drive.
When I run the above code in Google Colab, clearly my sqlite file is present in my drive. But whenever I run some query on this file, it says

```
# using the SQLite Table to read data.
con = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite') 

#filtering only positive and negative reviews i.e. 
# not taking into consideration those reviews with Score=3
filtered_data = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Reviews WHERE Score !=3",con)
```

DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM Reviews WHERE Score != 3 ': no such table: Reviews

Comment: Does `connect` raise an error if you provide a bogus file name? (One possibility is that you need to change your working directory to `/content/drive/My\ Drive/`.) Also, how are you confirming that the `Reviews` table is present in the database? (Another possibility is that the error message is correct and there's no such table.)

Comment: @BobSmith Thanks! Changing the directory to /content/drive/My\ Drive/ worked. I was using %cd / instead of %cd ./ to change directory.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have uploaded your file, click on the navigation pane on the left hand side. Under the Files tab, right click on your uploaded file and select 'Copy path'. Use this copied path in the connection:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('content/database.sqlite')
```